# Is there any way that my HTML securer could be exploited?

Tags: php, html, security, html-parsing, domdocument

I've finally managed to make a function which does the following:

1. Takes a string as input. This can be either an entire HTML document or a HTML "snippet" (even broken).
2. Creates a DOMDocument from this and loops through all nodes.
3. Whenever it encounters any node whose element is outside of a whitelist of basic structural elements, it "marks it for deletion". For example, `<script>` is not whitelisted.
4. Whenever any node has ANY attribute starting with "on", this is immediately removed with `removeAttribute`. The same goes for any "style" attribute, and any "href" attribute whose value starts with "javascript:".
5. When all nodes are looped through, the ones marked for deletion are looped over and deleted (`$node->parentNode->removeChild($node)`). This isn't done in the first loop because the parser becomes confused if you do that.
6. This document is now `saveHTML`ed and returned as a string, now representing a cleaned/secured HTML document/snippet.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to abuse this. Unless there is some bug in the DOM parser, which is off my hands/conscience.

But maybe there is another "onsomething" attribute or something else I haven't thought of?

I feel pretty confident in outputting any HTML from any untrusted external/user-provided source after it's been mangled through this function of mine, but perhaps I'm being cocky?

(I truly wish that `strip_tags` would do this on its own so that I didn't have to code my own thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent xss, all of the `on*` attributes are candidates for removal. Also `style` might have javascript in various ways in some browsers, as well as `href` (`javascript:`). SVG can I think include scripts and so on.

Look [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet) for a non-comprehensive list of how these sanitizers would be bypassed, and why it's very hard to build a sanitizer yourself.

Why not just use a known-good sanitizer like Google Caja, instead of reinventing them? It's a lot harder than you seem to think.

Comment: First of all, I naturally don't use anything made by Google. Secondly, any kind of third-party library is a massive security issue in itself, as you have to trust them in multiple ways. What are the other on* attributes? `javascript:` in `href`... Hmm... That's new to me.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and updated my question. Although I don't know what you mean by the SVG stuff.

Comment: I added a link to my answer. If you don't like Google, there are many other well-known sanitizers which you can use. Also 3rd party components are a managable risk (but you do have to manage that risk, that's true). Writing everything from scratch is a much greater risk as your example already indicates. Having said that, it is possible to write your own sanitizer, but thinking of all the potential attack vectors that others have already gone through while implementing the well known ones - that's not at all straightforward.

Comment: After reading through that link's list, not only will I throw all my work away and use a third-party HTML securer (not by Google), but I have a much deeper hate toward HTML, browsers and those who make these standards and software. That list was absolutely insane, and I didn't know about a fraction of these things. What an absolute garbage mess. How is this not mentioned very carefully on the `strip_tags` manual page? It boggles my mind. Anyone using `strip_tags` has *zero* security, and even my script, which I thought was safe, could have been bypassed in a million ways... Unbelievable.